# Reading groupings in a text file in R

Tags: r

I have a text file of many grouped sections like shown below (obviously different numbers in each group). I want to grab all of the X, Y, and Z columns within each grouping and place them into a dataframe. How could I do this? I also want to add an indicator column to identify which grouping the lines came from.

Here is a basic layout of how the text file looks...

```
Start Date:                 02/05/2020
Start Time:                 16:00:14

  Time         X     Y     Z
============   ===== ===== =====
000:00:00.05    3.50  9.00  8.50
000:00:00.10    3.50  8.50  9.00
000:00:00.15    5.00  8.00  9.50
000:00:00.20    5.00  9.00  8.50
000:00:00.25    5.00  9.00  6.50
000:00:00.30    3.50  9.50  7.00


Start Date:                 02/05/2020
Start Time:                 16:00:14

  Time         X     Y     Z
============   ===== ===== =====
000:00:00.05    3.50  9.00  8.50
000:00:00.10    3.50  8.50  9.00
000:00:00.15    5.00  8.00  9.50
000:00:00.20    5.00  9.00  8.50
000:00:00.25    5.00  9.00  6.50
000:00:00.30    3.50  9.50  7.00


Start Date:                 02/05/2020
Start Time:                 16:00:14

  Time         X     Y     Z
============   ===== ===== =====
000:00:00.05    3.50  9.00  8.50
000:00:00.10    3.50  8.50  9.00
000:00:00.15    5.00  8.00  9.50
000:00:00.20    5.00  9.00  8.50
000:00:00.25    5.00  9.00  6.50
000:00:00.30    3.50  9.50  7.00
```

I tried using this code but was only able to get the first line of each grouping...

```
export <- list.files(path=wd, pattern = "one.Export")
options(warn=-1)
dat <- readLines(export)
x_dat <- read.table(text = dat[grep("Start Time:", dat) + 4])[,2:4]
```

If I add rows lengths, I get back NA's...

```
x_dat <- read.table(text = dat[grep("Start Time:", dat) + 4])[1:5,2:4]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your data is all in a single file why would you need `list.files`?

Comment: Sometimes there are multiple text files in the same folder that need to be run with different scripts. But the text files are all in the same format for the groupings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this kind of text parsing is that one has to rely on the text being in the exact format specified in the question.

This will work for your example, but it will probably have to be modified for your own real data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

  readLines("~/data.txt")  %>%          # Read file into a vector of strings
  paste(collapse = "\n") %>%            # Stick them together with newlines
  strsplit("Start Date: +") %>%         # Split them into groups at the keyword
  unlist %>%                            
  `[`(-1) %>%    # Remove the empty first element
  lapply(function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "\n"))) %>%         # carve at line breaks
  lapply(function(x) grep("\\d", x, value = TRUE)) %>%      # keep only rows with numbers
  lapply(function(x) strsplit(x, " +")) %>%                 # carve at spaces
  lapply(function(x) cbind(rep(paste(x[[1]], x[[2]][3]), length(x) - 2),
                           do.call(rbind, x[-c(1:2)]))) %>% # Bind into rows and add labels
  {do.call(rbind, .)} %>%                                   # Stick groups together
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("Group_date", "Time", "X", "Y", "Z"))          # Make dataframe and name it
#>             Group_date         Time    X    Y    Z
#> 1  02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.05 3.50 9.00 8.50
#> 2  02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.10 3.50 8.50 9.00
#> 3  02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.15 5.00 8.00 9.50
#> 4  02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.20 5.00 9.00 8.50
#> 5  02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.25 5.00 9.00 6.50
#> 6  02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.30 3.50 9.50 7.00
#> 7  02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.05 3.50 9.00 8.50
#> 8  02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.10 3.50 8.50 9.00
#> 9  02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.15 5.00 8.00 9.50
#> 10 02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.20 5.00 9.00 8.50
#> 11 02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.25 5.00 9.00 6.50
#> 12 02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.30 3.50 9.50 7.00
#> 13 02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.05 3.50 9.00 8.50
#> 14 02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.10 3.50 8.50 9.00
#> 15 02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.15 5.00 8.00 9.50
#> 16 02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.20 5.00 9.00 8.50
#> 17 02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.25 5.00 9.00 6.50
#> 18 02/05/2020 16:00:14 000:00:00.30 3.50 9.50 7.00
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>